# Need assistance with lightbox form data being loaded onto html page using load()

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a lightbox with a form. The information being entered in the form is used to populate an html file that is being loaded and appended to my main html page using the load() function. I am able to load the file without any problems and the data shows. However, I would like to be able to display that data in another lightbox by using a click event on a button, then using prev() to find the data and display it. It does not work. I am suspecting that I may need to use the success event listener for $.ajax. However, I am not sure.

The code would be something like this.

Lightbox:

```
<div id="lightbox">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1">
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Load function:

```
$('#submit1').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $('div#result').append($('<div').load('file.html', function() {
      var input = $('#textbox1').val();
      $(this).find('td.data').text(input);
   });
});
```

The html where data will get loaded into:
`<div id="result"></div>`

File.html

```
   <table>
 <tr>
   <td>Cell 1</td><td class="data"></td><td><button value="View"></button>
 </tr></table>
```

I want to be able to click on the View button in the third td in table above and retrieve the text in td.data so that I can display it in another lightbox. It seems as if the text isn't available for me to do so, since it originally has no text. I can retrieve Cell 1 with no problem. Do I need to use ajax (success handler) here? If so, how would I append and load into page at same time? Thank you!

Best,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an `onclick` event handler after `File.html` is loaded.

```
$('div#result').append($('<div').load('file.html', function() {
    var input = $('#textbox1').val();
    $(this).find('td.data').text(input);
    $(this).find('button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.data').text();
        // do something with data
    });
});
```

or a better solution would be, if you would use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```
$(document).on('click', '#result button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.data').text();
    // do something with data
});
```

With this, you don't need to bind a handler every time you load `File.html`.
You don't even need to define this inside the `onready` handler.